# not able to find ''kubectl" : no such file or directory

Tags: 22.04, kubernetes

I am installing kubectl using [Kubernetes Install on Linux](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-linux) . I am on third steps `sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl` but I am getting this error `install: cannot stat 'kubectl': No such file or directory` . Kindly help.

Comment: Did you perform the optional step *2 Validate the binary (optional)*?

Comment: Yes @steeldriver I did. Output kubectl:ok